# what is meant by minted crowdsales?

Tags: crowdsale, ethereum-classic, openzeppelin, mint

I am new to ethereum smart contracts, I was going through minted crowdsale code for learning but couldn't figured out its use case or what is its purpose, precisely what does it mean?

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone explein me this Multi mint function (Solidity)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35097/can-someone-explein-me-this-multi-mint-function-solidity)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate for at least that question. Anyway, which part is unclear for you? The minting part, the crowdsale part, which? Also please share a link to the page where you found the code.

Comment: I found this link for minted crowdsale, https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol. I wanna know what does it actually mean by minted crowdsale? How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider three groups of crowdsales:

1. Tokens are minted on deployment, no new tokens are minted after that.
2. New tokens are minted with each new contribution.
3. None of the previous.

I think 2. can be called minted crowdsale.